# Given $f(x) =\begin{cases} x\sin(1/x) & x \neq 0,\\ 0 & x= 0, \end{cases} $ why is $f'(0)$ not zero?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives, indeterminate-forms

When we use our standard product and chain rules for when $x$ not equal to $0,$ our derivative function works.

But when $x=0,$ $f'(x)$ does not exist. But why can't we just use standard differentiation rule on $x=0$? Won't that mean $f'(0) = 0$?

Comment: Have you actually **tried** to use "standard differentiation on $x=0$"?

Comment: Exactly how would that work? If you show us what you have in mind someone can say what the error is.

Comment: An interesting follow-up question could be "*If $g(x)=x^n\sin(1/x)$, what size does $n$ need to be for $g'(x)$ to have a finite limit as $x\to 0$?*". Your answer shows that $n>1$. Hint: consider how $g'(x)\approx -x^{n-2}\cos(1/x)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is unfortunate that math gets taught in such a way that people think it's done by applying rules of that sort. It **relies on** many such rules, but they are only a tool.

Actually **understanding** the subject as opposed to applying such rules will remind you that the value of the derivative at a point is the slope of the curve at that point, and that depends on what happens in some interval surrounding that point, not just on the value of the function at that point alone. Thus when you are told that if $f(x) = 5$ then $f'(x) =0,$ it means that if there is some interval such that for all values of $x$ in that interval $f(x) = 5,$ then $f'(x)=0$ for every value of $x$ in the interior of that interval.

To say that $f'(x)=0$ because $f(x) = 5,$ when $f(x) = 5$ at just an isolated point, is nonsense. For example, suppose $f(x) = x^2 - 4.$ Then $f(3) = 3^2-4=5.$  But that doesn't mean $f'(3)=0.$ In fact $f'(x) = 2x,$ so $f'(3)=6.$

Since the usual rules don't apply at $0$ for the function you give us, you need to go back to the definition:
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(0+h) - f(0)} h.
$$
If that limit exists then $f'(0)$ exists; otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: Or to put it another way, those rules are actually theorems, with hypotheses - the hypotheses tend to get ignored in Calc I.

Comment: Ah I think I see. So basically, the derivative depends on some arbitrarily small interval around a point because it is ultimately a limit, which by definition depends on the neighborhood around a point. Is that correct?

Comment: @stthomas : Yes. It's a "local" property, and that means no matter how small you make the open neighborhood around it, you still have enough information to determine the derivative, but if it's not an open neighborhood but just one point, then it's not enough. The angle in a polygon is another example: If you see a small region around the vertex, then no matter how small it is, you can tell it's a 34^\circ$ angle, but if you see only that one point that is the vertex, then you can't tell.

Comment: @stthomas : typo: $34^\circ. \qquad$

Answer (score 4):

Standard differentiation gives us:

$$f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0} \sin \left( \frac 1x \right)$$

It's well-known that the limit doesn't exist. Hence $f'(0)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. But how come we can then just use the product and chain rules for f'(x)  when x not zero to get (-1/x)*cos(1/x) + sin(1/x)? What lets those rules valid on x not zero but when x = 0 they're invalid?

Comment: Because $f(x)$ is not equal to $x\sin(1/x)$ near the origin. (In mathspeak "near the origin" means "at and near the origin"). On the other hand, if 4x\\ne0$ then $f(t)$ _is_ equal to $t\sin(1/t)$ for all $t$ near $x$.

Comment: @stthomas At around any point $x \not = 0$ you can find an open interval on which $f$ is differentiable. That's enough for the chain rule to be applicable. And in fact you have: $f'(x) = \cos\left( \frac 1x \right) \cdot \frac {-1}{x^2}$ for the derivative

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are missing is the fact that, while we usually speak of the derivative at a point, actually the derivative tells us something about the function in a *neighbourhood* of the point. Therefore you cannot just take the definition $f(0)=0$ and take the derivative of $0$, because there is no neighbourhood of $0$ where this is true.

To make this more obvious, define some function $g$ as follows:
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}x & x\ne 0\\0 & x = 0\end{cases}$$
Obviously this function is simply $g(x)=x$. However if we would use just the functional term given for the point in question and derive that, we'd get at the (wrong) result:
$$g'(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x\ne 0\\0 & x = 0\end{cases}$$
Of course the correct derivative is $g'(x)=1$ everywhere, as it doesn't matter how we write down that function.

Answer (score 2):

That does not even exists.
In fact, $$f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0} \sin \left( \frac 1x \right)$$
Does not exist . Just consider: $$z_n  =\frac{1}{n\pi}\to 0~~~and~~~y_n  =\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi}\to 0$$
But for all n we have, 
$$\sin \left( \frac{1}{z_n} \right) = 0~~~~and ~~~~\sin \left( \frac{1}{y_n} \right) = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a function with cases for $x=a$ and $x \neq a$, to calculate $f'(a)$ you have to use the definition of the derivative and do it with the limit.

In your case you have a function with cases for $a=0$. Therefore to determinate $f'(a)=f'(0)$ you have to go with the definiton.

$$f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0} \sin \left( \frac 1x \right)$$

Since that limit does **NOT** exist, you can conclude that $f'(0)$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Another example.  Let
$$
\phi(x) = \begin{cases}
x, & x \ne 0
\\ \; \\
0, &x = 0\end{cases}\tag{1}
$$
In fact, this is exactly the function $\phi(x) = x$, but of course we can write it as (1).

But the point is: you cannot compute $\phi'(0)$ by differentiating the $0$ in (1) to get $0$. That method is just wrong.